# grep for only uppercase words

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I would like to find all words that all all uppercase, but when I do

```
grep -oP '\w*[A-Z]+\w*' *
```

I get

```
words.py:StringValue
words.py:WORDS
words.py:WORDS_ANSWERED
words.py:Answered
words.py:True
```

where I were hoping for

```
words.py:WORDS
words.py:WORDS_ANSWERED
```

**Question**

How can I make sure that only all uppercase words is outputted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this regex with word boundary on either side and by using `[A-Z0-9_]` instead of `\w`:

```
grep -H -oP '\b[A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9_]*\b' *

words.py:WORDS
words.py:WORDS_ANSWERED
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the `\w` in the output, don't include it in the pattern.

```
grep -oP '[A-Z]+' *
```

To get the expected output, though, you need to include underscores and word boundaries:

```
grep -oP '\b[A-Z_0-9]+\b'
```

If you want to avoid `____` and similar (are they common in Python code?), use

```
grep -oP '\b[A-Z_0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z_0-9]*\b'
```

Comment: If I do that, then `True` becomes `T` in the output.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes: Updated.

Comment: It will also match `___` which is without any uppercase letter.

Comment: @anubhava: OK, so add `| grep -v '^_*$'`

Comment: @choroba: I was not the one who downvoted but I can certainly upvote to negate a -1 However you may need to include `0-9` also since OP was using `\w`

Answer (score 0):

The regex thinks `S`, `A` and `T` are uppercase words. So this depends on how you define uppercase word. From your examples, it appears you're looking for something more like `^[A-Z_]+$`. Or, if by "uppercase word" you mean "no lowercase characters", `[^a-z]+$`